# What is the process of developing a scalable architecture for a web application?

Tags: web-applications, web, architecture, cloud

I am a beginner who is new to application development . I have heard many developers talk about developing a scalable architecture .I don't have much idea about architecture so I would like to know know more about what actually an architecture of a web application means and how to develop one for my own applications .
Any help will be highly appreciated .
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many aspects of a good Architecture (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_architecture). [Scalability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability) is just one of those(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement).

For a beginner, I hope these links will help:

1. http://fewagainstmany.com/blog/introduction-to-layered-architecture-part-one
2. http://blog.simcrest.com/what-is-3-tier-architecture-and-why-do-you-need-it/
3. Look into section "Scalability Options of the Design" @ http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70061/Architecture-Guide-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-N-tier-En

Please feel free to ask any further specific question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are interested in software architecture theory in general then look at the literature about MVC, SOA, WEB Frameworks using google.

But for a web developer today scalability usually means finding the right application framework and server environment to run your business logics and writing code which uses these nicely.

After you have your choice of language / set of languages (Ruby, Java, Python, .NET ...), one approach can be if you look at the currently available public cloud environments which frameworks are supported. Heroku, Engineyard, OpenStack, AppEngine, AmazonWS, Rightscale are just few of the popular examples of such platforms today.

[Autoscaling](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) on these platforms usually solves all your scaling problems.